# Can't get overflow scroll to work

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to be able to scroll within the page when the content collapses to the center-right (the content collapses/transforms upon clicking the sidebar label). I don't want there to be a main page scroll.

Here's a codepen, but the positioning is off because of the interface size,
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXKEpE

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    border: dotted 1px black;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .page-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: pink;
    transition: .2s ease;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: right center;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .toggle {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    transition: .2s ease;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  li {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: atialiased;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  li:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
  #sidebartoggler {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .toggle {
    left: 200px;
  }
  #sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .page-content {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler" name=" " value="" />

  <div class="page-wrap">

    <label for="sidebartoggler" class="toggle">☰</label>

    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Clients</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.page-wrap, body, html{
  height:100%;
}
```

You need this in your css for `height:100%` to work. Basically if you want to make something 100% of the page height, all of its ancestor needs to be 100%

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

```
page-wrap{
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: @rabbit.aaron yeah that is true. But if you think about, well from my point of view. His said we bar won't be a side bar in IOS. Even if it is an iPad,  we'll maybe, but still Vh units and for the most part I haven't had any issue using them.

Comment: `vh` has given me so much headache on iOS, now I just try my best to avoid using it. It doesn't work as expected until iOS 9 (or 9.0.2 ?), considering so many people still using lower version of iOS, I'll just stick to `height:100%` for now.